# Updating an Angular $scope variable from a jquery function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a $scope.varName = true; variable in a controller that I am trying to set to false inside a function in jQuery.

```js
var getActiveCarouselMeter = angular.element($('.getActiveCarouselMeter')).scope().activeCarouselMeter;
```

The code above accesses my $scope.varName variable however when I do this..

```js
getActiveCarouselMeter = false;
            angular.element($('.getActiveCarouselMeter')).scope().activeCarouselMeter = getActiveCarouselMeter;
```

My angular variable is not getting updated to false.

Hope that clears up some things.

Comment: so,what is the question?

Comment: Consider adding a bit more of code and elaborate what is the problem you are facing with this task.

Comment: `$scope.varName = false;` should do the trick. Seriously tho - post some code, all we can do is guess at this point

Comment: Indeed you asked no question so all that's left for me to say is that mixing Angular and jQuery never smells good...

Answer (score 1):

I think, depending on the context in which you set the variable, you will need to look at $scope.apply. Like if you are within some kind of async callback: a success handler provided by a jQuery library

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
  $scope.varName = false;
});
```

Comment: Although, I would wonder why one is using JQuery's ajax functionality over angular's $http.

Comment: Fair point, couldn't think of a real life example of the top of my head